# Inaccurate line reporting of React JS error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, runtime-error, reactjs

I have been having numerous issues with error reporting in React js. So the actual error will be correct, but the line reported will not be. I'm guessing this is because the JSX is converted into regular Javascript, thus either creating more or less lines of code. This makes it rather difficult to actually track down and fix these errors, when the console is telling me it occurs on line x and line x is a newline or other random code that is obviously not connected to the error. Has anyone else solved this issue?

I am using Google Chrome and I also have the react developer tools installed.

Comment: Have you tried using source maps? http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map

Comment: i've had issues debugging jsx with react using source maps. my line numbers are correct, but breakpoints will jump a few lines sometimes.

Comment: @MichaelCamden source maps look like they solve my problem rather well. However I have also stumbled upon another solution that is completely sufficient for me. In chrome (haven't tested this in firefox) if you click on the file and line number that pop up in the console, chrome will automatically open up the file in the debugger and jump to it. So at that point, I know where exactly the actual error is and then change it in source. But source maps are arguably better than my solution so if you want to write up an answer I'll mark it as solved for other devs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per our conversation via comments, a solution is to use Source Maps.